# How to get Image dynamically from image name stored in json file?

Tags: android, json

I have stored Image name(E.g. "Image1.png") in `JSON` file. And I have get that name using `JSONParser`. But the problem is that I am not able to display that image in `ImageView`.

Here is the code I have written:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewer);
for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);
    String varImage = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(varImage, "drawable" , getPackageName());                      
    imageView.setImageResource(resId);
    //code to add data in hash map
}
```

Comment: what is the resId returning?  Also give use the varImage value after you get it from the JSON

Comment: resId giving 0 and json date i.e. varImage is giving "Image1.jpg"

Comment: and you have a file in your drawable called Image1.jpg?  try running getResources().getIdentifier("Image1.jpg", "drawable" , getPackageName()); and see what it gives you

Comment: Where is that image stored? In your drawables folder? If your image name is image1.png, then when you're trying to do getIdentifier() send only "image1" instead of "image1.png" as parameter and see what resId you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must work.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewer);
for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);
    String varImage = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE).substring(0, c.getString(TAG_IMAGE).lastIndexOf('.');
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(varImage, "drawable" , getPackageName());                      
    imageView.setImageResource(resId);
    //code to add data in hash map
}
```

Comment: Glad :) But the way I'm parsing string may fail and it fails for 9-patch images. It is best to store only image name in JSON without its extension. So that you can straight away follow what you were doing earlier without any string parsing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggetion. I am making json file from php. I'll sure edit my php code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to get the drawable id:

```
try {
    Class res = R.drawable.class;
    Field field = res.getField("drawableName"); //Here you put your image name getting from json file
    int drawableId = field.getInt(null);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("MyTag", "Failure to get drawable id.", e);
}
```

After getting the drawable id, then you can set the drawable to ImageView.

Comment: Your code is not helping me out... I have put it in try catch but it is still demanding to put it in try catch.

Comment: please check the image name you are getting from json file. you have mention in code example image name as Image1 but capital alphabets are not accepted for Resource image names

Comment: But still I am getting resId = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code and let me know it works for you or not.

```
 imageview= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {

String varImage = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);

 String uri = "@drawable/"+ "varImage";

int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());


Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
imageView.setImageDrawable(res);
}
```

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app/com.voyageapp.PackageMainDetailsActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0